# Push Notification View the Particular View Controller by Tapping on Notification IOS7

Tags: ios, iphone, notifications

Hi in my application i have the push notification when user tap the notification its going to the main view controller i to view a particular view controller by tapping on the notification i have tried some methods its not working for me so please tell to make it done.

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken {
    const char* data = [deviceToken bytes];
    NSMutableString * token = [NSMutableString string];

    for (int i = 0; i < [deviceToken length]; i++) {
        [token appendFormat:@"%02.2hhX", data[i]];
    }

    NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"url?token=%@",token];

    NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:urlString];
    NSLog(@"token %@",urlString);


    NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    NSLog(@"request %@ ",urlRequest);
    NSData *urlData;
    NSURLResponse *response;
    urlData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:urlRequest returningResponse:&response error:nil];
    NSLog(@"data %@",urlData);
    [self clearNotifications];

}


-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelLocalNotification:notification];

    //My_specificViewController
    updatepoliticalViewController *ringingVC = [self.window.rootViewController.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"updatepoliticalViewController"];
    [self.window setRootViewController:ringingVC];
}
```

Tthe above i have tried its not working for please tell where I'm doing worng what is the correct way to make it done.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

Dont set as rootviewcontroller

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification {

     updatepoliticalViewController *ringingVC = [self.window.rootViewController.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"updatepoliticalViewController"];
     [self.navigationController pushViewController:ringingVC animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: Are you sure, the code you've posted has `Local` not `Remote` can you update your answer to show the remote code you used

Comment: @Erik i have used ur code but its showing error on navigationcontroller pls wt have to do now sir

Comment: u didnt use navigationController?

Comment: i didnt use navigation controller

Comment: try like `[self.window.rootViewController.navigationController pushViewController:ringingVC animated:YES];`

Comment: or `[self.window.rootViewController presentViewController:ringingVC animated:YES completion:NULL];`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49806/discussion-between-user3349668-and-erik)